# display: relative error: invalid property value when width and height of parent are set

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my h2 text "hover" above my images but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Developer Tools in chrome says that the display: relative is an invalid property value and I'm not sure why. I'm setting my h2 text as absolute and setting top/left at 0px but the text is still underneath the image. Please help.

**HTML**

```
<div class="cta-wrapper">
    <div class="cta">
        <img src="Photos/mypedal.png">
        <a href="Products/productroom.php"><h2>Product Room</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cta">
        <img src="Photos/signup.png">
        <a href="Users/createaccount.php"><h2>Sign Up</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cta">
        <img src="Photos/features.png">
        <a href=""><h2>Features</h2></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cta-wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.cta {
    display: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px 60px;
}

.cta a {
    display: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.cta h2 {
    display: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #BBBBBB;
}

.cta img {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `position: absolute;` and `position: relative;` **not** `display: absolute;` and `display: relative;`.

You are applying values for the `position` property to the `display` property.

Comment: Thank you. I got them mixed up somehow. I'm still pretty new to CSS.

Comment: No problem. It happens. Sometimes it just takes an extra set of eyes.